# Error : Serializer getting multiple values for argument 'instance'

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

I am new to Django

My task is to do CRUD operations using serializers, but this error has come

here's my function:

```
def updateemp(request,id):
    Updateemp = EmpModel.objects.get(id=id)
    form = CRUDSerializer (request.POST,instance=Updateemp)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request,'Record Updated Successfully...!:)')
        return render(request,'Edit.html',{"EmpModel":Updateemp})
```

serializer:

```
class CRUDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EmpModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

below is the error:

```
BaseSerializer.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'instance'
```

can someone tell me where I am going wrong in the syntax?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide de code of `CRUDSerializer` class.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: FULL error message should show you in which line you have problem - so first you could use `print(...)` (and `print(type(...))`, etc.) to see what you have in variables in this line. We can't see full error - so we don't know which line makes problem. And we can't run code  - to use `print()` - so you will have to do it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decided to serializer an instance, you don't need to put keyword "instance" to the serializer.

```
Updateemp = EmpModel.objects.get(id=id)
form = CRUDSerializer(Updateemp)
```

Btw, `EmpModel.objects.get(id=id)` might not return any object which could result in serializer error. Consider using `get_object_or_404` or `try catch` to prevent this error.